# Notify build status from Jenkins to Bitbucket Server

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server, bcbsn

We have installed Jenkins v2.7.3 and Bitbucket Server v4.9.1 on premise and would like to send build status as notifications from Jenkins to Bitbucket Server.

So far I have only found solutions (1 and 2) for Bitbucket Cloud, but nothing for Bitbucket Server. Any tip on how to make this happen?

1. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin
2. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+OAuth+Plugin

Comment: So were you able to make it work?

Comment: Could you use Bitbucket's REST API from Jenkins as part of a post build task? https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might get some use out of the [stash plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+%28Stash%29+Notifier+Plugin) as [BitBucket is based on Stash code](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-rebrand-faq-779298912.html).

What Atlassian had to say:

```
We have unified our Git products under the Bitbucket name. With
Bitbucket, now you have a range of options that can be adopted by teams
of all sizes and requirements: Bitbucket Cloud (previously known as
Bitbucket), Bitbucket Server (previously known as Stash) and Bitbucket
Data Center (previously known as Stash Data Center).
```

About the plugin:

```
This plugin notifies an Atlassian Stash instance of Jenkins builds in
progress and of their results. The build results will show up in the
commit list in Stash or in a Stash pull request and provide immediate
and easy to scan feedback about a commit. It is possible to navigate 
from build result information in Stash directly to the build in 
question. The plugin can be configured on a per-job basis, globally 
for all Jobs or both to minimize the configuration overhead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Build status can be posted seamlessly from Jenkins's [Bitbucket server integration plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/). This plugin is created and maintained by Atlassian.

However, You will have to upgrade the Bitbucket server from v4.9.1 to at least v5.6. Preferably to v7.4+ to make use of new [build functionality](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-7-4-release-notes-1013849643.html#BitbucketServer7.4releasenotes-cicd) within Bitbucket Server.

Answer (score 1):

**Bitbucket Server Notifier** plugin for Jenkins did the job for me (Jenkins integration with Bitbucket Server - formerly known as Stash).

https://plugins.jenkins.io/stashNotifier/#documentation
Usage: https://github.com/jenkinsci/stashnotifier-plugin/blob/release/1.x/readme.md

Answer (score 0):

You need Stash Pull Request Builder Plugin
This Jenkins plugin builds pull requests from an Atlassian Stash server and will report the test results as a comment. This plugin was inspired by the GitHub & BitBucket pull request builder plugins

https://plugins.jenkins.io/stash-pullrequest-builder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the Stash Notifier plugin now works with Job DSL